# What exactly does the Scipy: signal.detrend (type='constant' ) do a time series data set and can I reverse signal.detrend in python?

Tags: python, scipy, time-series

I am currently trying to model a Multivariate Random Forest on time series data. The only way I get decent test accuracies on the model is to detrend the data before modelling using the scipy detrend type=constant (the type=linear does not give good accuracies) with the following code:

`detrended =signal.detrend(feature, axis=-1, type='constant', bp=0, overwrite_data=True)`

After I model the data I want to show the results of the model as the original units before detrending.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to reverse signal.detrend?
2. What exactly does the signal.detrend (type=constant) do to the data?

In the Scipy documentation I am aware of the following:

type{‘linear’, ‘constant’}, optional
The type of detrending. If type == 'linear' (default), the result of a linear least-squares fit to data is subtracted from data. If type == 'constant', only the mean of data is subtracted.

However when I look at the data after performing signal.detrend (type=constat) it does not simply subtract the mean from the data as the documentation suggests.

Any guidance on how to reverse the detrend function and what the detrend type=constant does to the data would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar question and figured I'd look in the source files. For your case it seems it literally substracts the np.mean() of the dataset:

```
    if type in ['constant', 'c']:
        ret = data - np.expand_dims(np.mean(data, axis), axis)
        return ret
```

Further in the source code there seems to be no difference whether you do overwrite_data=True/False. It runs the code above without checking this attribute, for as far as I can see.

Also, if I manually substract the mean vs. signal.detrend with type='constant' I see no differences in my data. Therefore I think it could be something you're doing.

[image]

If the above answers your question, obviously to reverse the detrending adding the original mean should do the job.